# Laravel : BelongstoMany relationship implementation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

i have following tables

```
1.Shops  (shop_id , company_id , name, latitude, logntitude, phone)

2.packages(package_id, company_id, cost, value, expire_date)

3.shop_packages (package_id, shop_id)
```

and i am  trying to access this  shops associated with package as below

**Package Model**

```
public  function  shop():BelongsToMany{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Shop::class,'shop_packages','package_id','package_id');
}
```

**Shop Model**

```
 public  function  package(){
  return   $this->belongsToMany(Package::class,'shop_packages','shop_id','shop_id');
}
```

now when i try below it returns me shop with empty result while there is data available ,

```
 Package::with('shop')->where('package_id',$request['package_id'])->first();
```

i am using laravel 8.x for this project . Can someone please help me to sort the issue

**Shop Table**

[image]

**Package Table**

[image]

**shop_packages**
[image: shop_packages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You entered the wrong foreign key in the relation. The belongsToMany relation should be declared like this

**Package Model**

```
public  function  shops():BelongsToMany{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Shop::class,'shop_packages','package_id','shop_id');
    //you can also just ignore the foreign keys since they follow naming standards
    //return $this->belongsToMany(Shop::class,'shop_packages');
}
```

**Shop Model**

```
 public  function  packages(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Package::class,'shop_packages','shop_id','package_id');
    //same here
    //return $this->belongsToMany(Package::class,'shop_packages');
}
```

You should also use plural to better express the many to many relation

```
Package::with('shops')->where('package_id',$request['package_id'])->first();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , this is still returning me empty shops  #relations: array:1 [
    "shops" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1405
      #items: []
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
  ]

Comment: @stackoverflowaccount then check the data in your database. The code is correct.

Comment: i have added screenshots for all 3 tables could you pleas have a look ,

Comment: @stackoverflowaccount try it statically with `Package::with('shops')->where('package_id',1)->first();`

Comment: i tried that already but it did not work , is there any other way to implement except belongstomany , i dont knwo why its not working ,

Comment: @stackoverflowaccount In your shop model, did you define `protected $primaryKey = 'shop_id';` since you are not using the conventional primary key `id`?

Comment: yes . that is added right under hasfactory  
   class Shop extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'shop_id';

Comment: okay its sorted, package_id  was missing in packages model as you asked for shop model i double checked packages model and it was missing  , Thanks a lot for your time and help really appreciate it , and love Laravel community :-)